# Foreign Characters in include file show as question marks

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, include

I have a curious problem that has me stumped. I have a php page that has an include file for multiple languages. For some reason the foreign characters on the main PHP file display properly, but the foreign characters from the include file change into question marks.

The include sequence is *index.php > languages.php* (determines the language) > *french.php* (an array of French text for the site).

I am working in WAMP running on Windows 7. I have included

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

in the head of the main document. I have also confirmed that the editor is set to UTF-8. This is a small static site so there is no database.

I've never come across anything like this before and nothing similar has come up in my searches. I would really appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve this.

Thanks,
Penny

Comment: What kind of question mark? A pure little "?", or a question mark in a black diamond �?

Comment: I'm closing this as duplicate of the canonical reference for now. Please try every relevant step mentioned there, particularly the one about **HTTP headers**. My suspicion would be that that's the problem. If it doesn't help, add more details about each relevant step mentioned so we can narrow down the problem.